# Firebase RealTime Database + Google Sign In

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How can I use Firebase Realtime Database when I only want to use the Google Sign-In? Is there a way to tell the database that I am logged in?

As default the rules say:

```
write: auth != null 
read: auth != null
```

How can I tell the DB that after I signed in through Google Sign-In that `"auth != null"`.

I hope I made myself clear, if not please let me know.

**EDIT:**
I changed the Rules to the below but still, nothing

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.provider == 'google'",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.provider == 'google'"
  }
}
```

So it seems like I am prepared because in the Rule-Simulator it works but I still don't know how to tell the DB that after I signed in to my Google Account in my Android phone.

After I login I do a simple write:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message");
mDatabaseReference.setValue("HELLO");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Google Sign-In results in a valid account and credential.  You then need to use that information to authenticate with Firebase.  The steps are outlined in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

This is the sample code in the documentation that uses the Google Sign-In credential to create an authenticated Firebase user:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(GoogleSignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

You can then set your database security rules to limit access to authorized users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob, that was exactly what I was looking for. It is now working as expected.